# List all ".csv" filename and then enter corresponding code to plot the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is a folder which contains lot of data for example the folder contains ".html" files , ".jpeg" files, ".pdf"files, ".csv" files(There are plenty of ".csv" excel sheets in the folder containing different file names). Here is the code which list only csv files.

Is there a way where in when i list all ".csv" files i will enter the corresponding code to plot graph.

```
    import os
    path = "F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary"
    files = []
    # r=root, d=directories, f = files
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for file in f:
            if '.csv' in file:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
    for f in files:
        print(f)
```

When i run the above code i get output as:

```
F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary\Test_Summary_1.csv 
F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary\Test_Summary_2.csv
F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary\Test_Summary_3.csv
```

Actually i want Output to be displayed as:

```
0-Test_Summary_1.csv
1-Test_Summary_2.csv
2-Test_Summary_3.csv
3-Test_Summary_4.csv
4-Test_Summary_5.csv
5-Test_Summary_6.csv etc
```

How do i modify it to get as said above??

Comment: You need to know the csv file to plot before hand

Comment: there are plenty of ".csv" excel sheets in the folder containing different file names

Comment: Do you know which one you'd like to plot?

Comment: All ".csv" sheets contains 2 columns i will always plot column 1 vs column 2.

Comment: Do you intend to plot all of the '.csv' files in the same plot or different subplots?

Comment: i will select particular csv sheet to plot

Comment: For eg:```0-Test_Summary_1.csv
1-Test_Summary_2.csv
2-Test_Summary_3.csv
3-Test_Summary_4.csv
4-Test_Summary_5.csv ```i will sect the code to plot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193994/discussion-between-priyanka-mishra-and-newkid).

Answer (score 1):

If you run into trouble that the files aren't listed in the right order you can just sort the list of filenames as follows:

```
>>> x = ['abc_1.csv', 'abc_2.csv', 'abc_0.csv'] 
>>> x.sort()
>>> x
['abc_0.csv', 'abc_1.csv', 'abc_2.csv']
```

If you know which csv data you'd like to plot. You can read the file into a `numpy` array as follows

```
from numpy import loadtxt
data = loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',')
```

Then you can just plot the data using matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Comment: How do i list all the csv sheets??

Comment: To list all the csv sheets you've already written code in the question right? Do you have any problems with that?

Comment: My only concern is how do i list file names as follows ```0-Test_Summary_1.csv 1-Test_Summary_2.csv 2-Test_Summary_3.csv 3-Test_Summary_4.csv 4-Test_Summary_5.csv``` then i will write a code to plot it

Comment: When i run the program the output is displayed as ```F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary\Test_Summary_1.csv F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary\Test_Summary_2.csv``

Comment: I think sorting filenames by order is another question. Could you create another post. Id answer there. On SO avoid asking multiple questions in a single post

Comment: i want it to be displayed as ``0-Test_Summary_1.csv 1-Test_Summary_2.csv 2-Test_Summary_3.csv 3-Test_Summary_4.csv 4-Test_Summary_5.```